# "&" in for loop in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I am using & to run multiple programs together in for-loop in bash shell script

for example,

```
for ((i=1;i<=45;i=i+1))
do
    
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 4 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 4 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 5 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 5 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 6 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 6 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 3 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 3 --seed ${i} 


done
```

and I did not put & in that last sentence,
because it would be terrible if I run &... 45*8 programs together

but It still runs more programs than 8 programs together.

[image]

Why this problem is happening?

Comment: Perhaps this a job for GNU parallel?

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel -j8 python pythonfile.py --gpu {2} --seed ${1} ::: {1..45} ::: 4 4 5 5 6 6 3 3
```

Runs 8 jobs at a time 360 in total.

Comment: thank you for answering the question!
I didn't know this way and it is more effective. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have to `wait` for the background jobs to finish before starting another iteration:

```
for ((i=1;i<=45;i=i+1))
do    
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 4 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 4 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 5 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 5 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 6 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 6 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 3 --seed ${i} &
    python pythonfile.py --gpu 3 --seed ${i} &
    wait
done
```

`wait` is a shell builtin btw, run `help wait` in your shell for the  help page.